# What is the best practice to access cookies from postman?

Tags: php, symfony, postman

below is my code to set cookies

```
$expireTime = time() + 3600;
$tokenPayload = [
    'user_id' => $token->getUser()->getId(),
    'email'   => $token->getUser()->getEmail(),
    'exp'     => $expireTime
];

$jwt = JWT::encode($tokenPayload, getenv("JWT_SECRET"));
$useHttps = true;
setcookie("jwt", $jwt, $expireTime, "/", "", $useHttps, true);
```

And it set perfectly as image below
[image]

but when i try access that cookie it return null by below code

```
return  $request->cookies->get("jwt") ? true : false
```

I am trying to access cookie in symfony code to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question when you are working on local you have to send $useHttps as false to set cookie

```
  //$useHttps = true;
    $useHttps = false;
    setcookie("jwt", $jwt, $expireTime, "/", "", $useHttps, true);
```